# TinyMapper null checking in bind expression

Tags: c#, tinymapper

Below are my classes

```
public class CommonClassSource
{
public int Id {get;set;}
}

public class CommonClassDestination
{
public int Id {get;set;}
}

public class SourceClass
{
public CommonClassSource CommonSource {get;set;}
}

public class DestinationClass
{
public CommonClassDestination CommonDestination {get;set;}
}
```

Is there any way to add null-checking in config.Bind? For example: here, check if source.CommonSource is null

```
TinyMapper.Bind<SourceClass, DestinationClass>(config => {
config.Bind(source => source.CommonSource.Id,
                  target => target.CommonDestination.Id));
});
```

Comment: TinyMapper, has one watcher. Is essentially abandonedware on github. My suggestion is use another solution

Answer (score 0):

If all you wanted to have the case handled that it there isn't an issue when `source.CommonSource` is `null`, the following script should work for you.

```
    static bool isSourceNull;
    public static void Main()
    {

        Func<SourceClass,object> getSCI = GetSourceClassId;
        Func<DestinationClass, object> getDCI = GetDestClassId;
        TinyMapper.Bind<SourceClass, DestinationClass>(config => {
            config.Bind(source=>getSCI,
                          target =>getDCI);
    });
    }
    static object GetSourceClassId(SourceClass source)
    {
        isSourceNull = source.CommonSource == null;
        if (isSourceNull) return -1;
        else return source.CommonSource.Id;
    }
    static object GetDestClassId(DestinationClass destinationClass)
    {
        if (isSourceNull) 
        {
        destinationClass.CommonDestination = null;
            return -1;
        }
        else if (destinationClass.CommonDestination != null)
            return destinationClass.CommonDestination.Id;
        else return -1;
    }
```

Comment: I suppose, returning -1 may have side effects.

Comment: So what would you want to have? To you just not want the function to execute if it's null?

Comment: If I understood your answer correctly, target.CommonDestination.Id will have a value of -1 if source.CommonSource == null, right? But I think, target.CommonDestination should be null if source.CommonSource is null

Comment: I changed my answer. I understand your question now the following way: If source.CommonSource==null you want that the target.CommonDestination is set to null. Sorry, if I again misunderstood you